# Show divs in pair

Tags: html, css, alignment

[image]

I need to show `div` in the pair of two in each line but when the width of a div is too long then the long div should be placed in next line and other small div should take the vacant place in above line.

```css
.items {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items .item {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"> AAX </div>
  <div class="item"> G-TEST </div>
  <div class="item"> AGENCY </div>
  <div class="item"> Y2SP </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, and where is the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using floats you could use Flexbox.

```
.items {
    overflow: hidden; 
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```